# trying to add title over video using FFmPeg lib

Tags: android, android-ffmpeg

I am using Ff-mpeg lib for adding text over video. lib loaded successfully but at time of execution it gives me error.

this is my string showing error command::

```
String tetxcommand[]=new String[]{"ffmpeg -i /Phone storage/video.mp4 -vf drawtext=text='HELLLLLLO':x=10:y=H-th-10: fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:fontsize=12:fontcolor=white:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=5:shadowy=5 /Phone storage/video.mp4"};
```

There is my code and how i am using FFmpeg lib
(i have created 2 method 1 for load ffmpeg and 1 for excute and i am calling excute method under loadffmpedlLibrarymethod() on success methos)

```
public void LoadFFmpegLibrary()
{
    if(ffmpeg==null)
    {
        ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
        try {
            ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    Log.e("ffmpef","Start to load");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure() {
                    Log.e("ffmpef","failed to load");
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.e("ffmpef","load Successfully");
                    ExcuteFfmpefLibrabry(mutevideocommand);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {}
            });
        } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
            // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
            Log.e("ffmpef",e.toString());
        }

    }


}

public void ExcuteFfmpefLibrabry(String command[])
{

    ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
    try {
        // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
        ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.e("ffmpef","Exaction Start");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {}

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.e("ffmpef","failed to Excute Command");
                Log.e("ok",message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                Log.e("ffmpef","Video Edited Successfully");
                Log.e("ok",message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        Log.e("ffmpef",e.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
  configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Unrecognized option 'i /Phone storage/video.mp4 -b:v 2097k -s 160x120 -r 30 -aspect 4:3 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -strict experimental /Phone storage/video.mp4'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Comment: Did you try spliltting the string into multiple arguments as I proposed? Also, it seems that you can ommit the first `ffmpeg` item.

Answer (score 1):

You must split the arguments as separate string objects, since now the binary perceives them as a single argument.

```
String tetxcommand[]=new String[]{"-i", "/Phone storage/video.mp4", "-vf", "drawtext=text='HELLLLLLO':x=10:y=H-th-10:fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:fontsize=12:fontcolor=white:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=5:shadowy=5", "/Phone storage/video.mp4"};
```

From the code you posted it seems that `ffmpeg` is actually not needed in the array, all that is needed are the actual arguments (judging from the comment about version).

Comment: still the same error

Comment: @vikram - are you sure? Because in your existing output it atctually shows the whole command in quotes as a single argument. In this case, it can't be so since the arguments are separated.